# Got error when run async select with EF Core dbcontext

Tags: c#, asynchronous, dbcontext, ef-core-3.1

```
public class Person 
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext 
{
    public DbSet<Person> People { get; set; }
}

public class Program 
{
    public void Main() 
    {
        using var context = new ApplicationDbContext(*configuration here*);
        var doWorks = Enumerable.Range(0, 1000).Select(x => context.People.AsNoTracking().ToArrayAsync());
        await Task.WhenAll(doWorks);
    }
}
```

I get this error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'A second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed. This is usually caused by different threads using the same instance of DbContext. For more information on how to avoid threading issues with DbContext, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2097913.'

How can I run multi tasks like that and get rid of that error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to create a new `ApplicationDbContext` object inside each task:

```
public class Program {
    public void Main() {
        var doWorks = Enumerable.Range(0, 1000).Select(async x => {
                          using var context = new ApplicationDbContext(*configuration here*);
                          await context.People.AsNoTracking().ToArrayAsync();
                      });
        await Task.WhenAll(doWorks);
    }
}
```

Notice I made your lambda `async` and used `await`. Otherwise, the context would get disposed before the query is finished.

If you're doing this as a load test, that's fine. Just be aware that in some cases, executing 1000 tasks simultaneously might perform worse than other ways.

Comment: The problem is that, in my new blazor app, it is very difficult to make ApplicationDbContext transient due to tons of dependencies. Any suggestion?

Comment: I can't help you there. I didn't realize you were using Blazor. I've never used it. You should probably mention that in your question.